# Potential bugs I've found so far on the new reputation tab

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, profile-page

I think I've found about three bugs so far in the new reputation page. **First**:

Go to the [Robert's](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/102937/robert-harvey?tab=reputation) reputation tab and look on 25th February. You'll see he received one point for a deleted post.

There are two possibilities:

- Robert just got a point for deleting a post
- Robert downvoted a person which then deleted his post (which is unnacceptable, because downvotes are private)

**Second**, just a typo:

I have downvoted a question. It now says, in my tab, "downvote". Shouldn't it be "downvoted"?

**Third**:

Sometimes*, when showing details about a given day, there aren't arrows to expand post votes (maybe a protection against overhead?) (example on [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/135201/nick-craver?tab=reputation&sort=post) page)

[image: maybe protection against overhead]

*It only spawns the expand arrows for the first day that you open..

Comment: All of these are being fixed for a build deploying shortly.

Comment: @NickCraver: So the last one was a bug, too ? Could you be more descriptive about that one, please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These are now fixed:

1. These are now hidden, we did not intend to expose downvote activity in this way.
2. This was a typo, it'll say "downvoted" or "undownvoted" now.
3. This was a JS bug (actually an old one) that was not using a recursive callback for future loads...this will get a total refactor later, but it works for now.

Comment: So ajax response was correct but callback function did something wrong?

Answer (score 3):

To expand on point three, it only shows arrows for the **first** day that you expand.

For example, on [Nick Craver's profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/135201/nick-craver?tab=reputation), if I expand Feb 24 *then* Feb 23, only arrows are shown for Feb 24.

[image: Example 1]

If I then reload the page and expand Feb 23 *then* Feb 24, only arrows are shown for Feb 23.

[image: Example 2]

All the automatically opened days always have the arrows.

---

I also noticed that if you expand an arrow inside one of the open days instead, then expanding any other day does not show arrows either.

[image: Example 3]

it appears to be linked to the first expand event.